# How to interpret results from the data if Levene's test is violated?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, assumptions, ancova, levenes-test

I'm doing ANCOVA analysis. So, the assumption of Levene's test is violated which means I have to run a non-parametric test. Does that mean I can't interpret other results that I obtained from the data (e.g can I still reject or accept the null hypothesis if the Levene's test is violated?)

Comment: Why do you have to use a nonparametric test?

Comment: Null hypothesis of which test? You mention three: ANCOVA, Levene's test, and some unnamed nonparametric test. Each test has it's own null and alternative hypothesis. Also: Welcome to CV, Lavvanya!

Comment: I'm really not sure, honestly.  I watched a youtube video and it said if the assumption of the Levene's test is violated then I have to run a nonparamatric test and I have not yet leaned this at school.

Comment: Research question

Is there any difference in the change of maximal ventilation of oxygen before and after the 12 week training period between the two types of exercise groups in a group of healthy males once the age is controlled for?

Hypothesis

H0: There is no significant difference in the mean of the change of maximal ventilation of oxygen between the two exercise groups 

Ha: There is significant difference in the mean of change of maximal ventilation of oxygen of the two exercise groups once the age is controlled

Comment: I'm doing my ANCOVA analysis based on this. So, I only have one null hypothesis. The Levene's test is the assumption to run my ANCOVA. I'm not sure what I have to do after doing all my assumptions